# Can you animate circles on mapbox, and also, just have hollow circles

Tags: google-maps, geometry, jquery-animate, mapbox

I know you can animate circles on google maps , see example

http://jsbin.com/nuwem/1/edit?html,output

```
 .....But can you do the same thing on Mapbox
```

I am creating a live earthquake map www.livehazards.com. Each earthquake mag is respresent by a circle

I would just like the outline of the circle and to be able to animate it.

I have tried using circle-stroke for just the outline but it did not work

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To animate your circle you can simply change its paint property several times: `map.setPaintProperty('yourmarker', 'circle-radius', 20)`

If you only want the circle outline, set `"circle-opacity":0` and `"circle-stroke-width": 1`.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/eddydg/pen/ZaMPOq?editors=1010)

```js
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
    center: [ 2.35, 48.85 ],
    zoom: 3
});

map.on('load', () => {
  let radius = 1;

  map.addLayer({
        "id": "points",
        "type": "circle",

        // Create the marker
        "source": {
            "type": "geojson",
            "data": {
                "type": "FeatureCollection",
                "features": [{
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [ 2.35, 48.85 ]
                    }
                }]
            }
        },

        // Draw the circle
        "paint": {
          "circle-opacity": 0,
          "circle-stroke-width": 1,
          "circle-stroke-color": "#000",
          "circle-radius": radius,
          "circle-radius-transition": {
            "duration": 0
          }
        }
    });

    // Animate the circle
    setInterval(() => {
      map.setPaintProperty('points', 'circle-radius', radius);
      radius = ++radius % 30;
    }, 50);
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks Hmmm,...... I can copy my earthquake code and the circle stroke function working on Codepen ........but............it is not working on my real website for some reason www.livehazards.com ....when I look in the error log it comes up with these errors

Comment: Error: layers.earthquake-layer.paint.circle-stroke-width: unknown property "circle-stroke-width"
    at Function.module.exports.emitErrors (validate_style.js:8)
    at Style._validate (style.js:720)
    at Style.addLayer (style.js:408)
    at module.exports.addLayer (map.js:728)
    at module.exports.<anonymous> ((index):555)
    at module.exports.fire (evented.js:81)
    at module.exports._render (map.js:1092)
fire @ evented.js:91
evented.js:91

Comment: Error: layers.earthquake-layer.paint.circle-stroke-color: unknown property "circle-stroke-color"
    at Function.module.exports.emitErrors (validate_style.js:8)
    at Style._validate (style.js:720)
    at Style.addLayer (style.js:408)
    at module.exports.addLayer (map.js:728)
    at module.exports.<anonymous> ((index):555)
    at module.exports.fire (evented.js:81)
    at module.exports._render (map.js:1092)

Comment: @CharlesHarrison There aren't much to it, you just need a source and a circle layer that you paint. Are you sure that you use a `"type":"circle"` for your layer?

Comment: Hey, thanks yes I am using "type": "Circle" on my website. The weird thing is....I copied my main code from my website to codepen and Circle-Stroke workedd....but  it will not work on my wordpress site.

Comment: Thank you before for providing the example of an animate circle of Mapbox......How would you go about animating a circle on a click, Circles imported from a geojson file. The modified code has been posted an answer but I cannot get it to work on codepen

Comment: You first need to know on which circle you clicked. You can use a listener for this `map.on('click', 'Circles', e => onClickedCircle(e))` then `map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point)` will give you the clicked feature.
At this moment you can clear a possible previous `setInterval()` and create a new one to animate the clicked Circle layer.

Comment: Well I managed to get an animation going with hovering (BUT) Circle strok e and Circle Stroke Width won't be recognised by my website. Do you have any idea why. Check out this link http://livehazards.com/cat/ and look in the inspection log .....It can get it working on Codepen but not on wordpress??

Comment: Or check http://livehazards.com/animation-test/ ....I tried just uploading your code....It won't recognise Circle Stroke or Width?

Comment: I know this thread is old, and the API has changed a bunch since 2017, but I'm curious about why all of the "animate a circle" examples I see are setting the transition time to 0 and then using a timer to change each frame. Why not try to transition it back and forth?

Comment: @DMack it is just simpler to do `radius = ++radius % 30` than handling a "growing" and a "shrinking" phase. There wasn't too much thought put into the animation type

Answer (score 1):

```
 var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
center: [ 2.35, 48.85 ],
zoom: 3
```

});

```
map.on('load', function() {
     let radius = 1;
   map.addSource("earthquakes", {
    type: "geojson",
    data: "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_day.geojson",
});
  map.addLayer({
    "id": "earthquake-layer",
    "type": "circle",
    "source": "earthquakes",
    "paint": {
      "circle-opacity": 0.4,
      "circle-color": "#830300",
      "circle-stroke-width": 2,
      "circle-stroke-color": "#fff",
      "circle-radius": {
            "property": "mag",
            "base": 2.5,
            "stops": [
                [{zoom: 0,  value: 2}, 1],
                [{zoom: 0,  value: 8}, 40],
                [{zoom: 11, value: 2}, 10],
                [{zoom: 11, value: 8}, 2400],
                [{zoom: 20, value: 2}, 20],
                [{zoom: 20, value: 8}, 6000]
              "circle-radius-transition": {
        "duration": 0
      }
            ]
        }
    }
});
setInterval(() => {
  map.setPaintProperty('eaarthquake-layer', 'circle-radius', radius);
  radius = ++radius % 30
}, 50);
```

});